# Why are the timestamps all delayed with Rails and Postgres?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I'm using the following to display the time at which a musing entry was created:

```
<%= l musing.created_at, :format => "%d/%m/%y at %I:%M %p" %>
```

And the time is delayed by 5 hours, for example if I generate a musing at "2012-10-30 19:21:35 -0700", this is the time displayed:

```
31/10/12 at 02:21 am  by me@benigeri.com
```

Comment: What timezone (UTC offset) is your server in? What about your database?

Comment: Is the field a `timestamp` or a `timestamptz` in the database table?

Comment: @MattBall I don't know what timezone offset my server is in, I'm located in Palo Alto, CA, and this happens both on local host and heroku.

Comment: @CraigRinger I'm not sure, I just added 't.timestamps' in the migration file, so I am using that.

Comment: @Craig: Rails implies `timestamp` in the database and everything normalized to UTC in the database as well.

Comment: Add `%z` or `%Z` to your `:format` and you'll see what timezone Rails is using.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks. As you may've guessed I don't generally work with Rails. What an odd way of doing it ... they could use `timestamptz` and either set `timezone` to `UTC` and it'd (IMO) make much more sense than storing timestamps that're *assumed* to be UTC.

Comment: @Craig: Come to Whistler for Australia Day and we'll grumble and complain about ActiveRecord's strange and bizarre ideas about databases over a pint or eleven. Too much opinion and not enough good sense.

Comment: This [related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860) may help to understand how it works.